# Magento - cms page title in a static block

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Is there a way to get the current cms page title in a static block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "yes" but read it as "no".

The [list of default markup tags](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/cms/markup_tags) is quite limited and doen't give you such a possibility. However you can create your own module which will add a block which will print out a title of a CMS page by given ID. So it all comes down how badly you need it an how much effort are you ready to invest into it.

Comment: Thanks @Tim that answer has given me idea.

Comment: I also would add this as possible solution: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/injecting-variables-into-a-magento-cms-static-block/